# not getting update in Google analytics Android

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have implemented Google analytics in App. here is my code

```
   mTracker.setScreenName("NavMain-Google-Analytics");
    mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

I am not getting any updation on:

https://analytics.google.com/analytics

how much time it takes to update on google analytics?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that maybe it won't show up immediately and are you sure that the API calls you're using are dispatching metrics events to Google Analytics?

Comment: how much time take to update on  google analytics?